# How to make continuous SpeechRecognition more efficient for IoT UWP?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to continuously listen the IoT device for a specific keyword like "Alexa". And when triggered I would like to further recognise the command to execute.

Currently I'm using an infinite loop which does not seem efficient since the IoT has 2GB of RAM and hence lags a lot. Though this solution seem to work on x64 environment.

```
private async void SetupTheContinuousSpeechRecognitionForAlexa()
{
    try
    {
        speechRecognizerAlexa = new SpeechRecognizer();
        speechRecognizerAlexa.Timeouts.BabbleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
        speechRecognizerAlexa.Timeouts.InitialSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
        speechRecognizerAlexa.Timeouts.EndSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
        speechRecognizerAlexa.Constraints.Add(new SpeechRecognitionListConstraint(new string[] { "alexa", "tiger" }));
        await speechRecognizerAlexa.CompileConstraintsAsync();
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var speechResult = await speechRecognizerAlexa.RecognizeAsync();
                if (speechResult.Confidence == SpeechRecognitionConfidence.High || speechResult.Confidence == SpeechRecognitionConfidence.Medium || speechResult.Confidence == SpeechRecognitionConfidence.Low)
                {
                    IsAlexaVoiceTriggered = true;
                    var helloResult = PlayTheString("How can I help you", false);
                    OnSpeechRecognitionCommandClicked(); 
                }
                else if (isSpeechEnabled)
                {
                    IsAlexaVoiceTriggered = false;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.log.Error("Failed in SetupTheContinousSpeechRecognitionForAlexa " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Has anyone else tried to achieve this in an IoT environment if so how can I further optimize this?

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient using Cortana's engine?

Comment: It would but I have my own custom AI engine so thought I would give it a rather personal touch.

Comment: As you say the IoT device has 2GB of RAM and works on x64 environment, I assumption that you are using MinnowBoard Max device. Am I right?

Comment: I'm using a RPi 2/3 with custom added mic hardware.

Comment: You could make sure the USB microphone is showing up under “Connected devices. Then make sure below line is added to the test app’s package.appmanifest file under “Capabilities” item group. <DeviceCapability Name="microphone" /> [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a31f9777-d715-42d8-8964-7774b35243e9/speech-recognition-on-raspberry-pi-2?forum=WindowsIoT). 
The code is running successfully on my RPi3 and the keyword "Alexa" can be triggered. Could you provide more details about what makes you have "lag a lot" feeling? Is that while loop?

Comment: @JamesLiu : Well I was targeting min version as Anniversary update earlier, but now I downgraded to a lower version and it works pretty good. I think there was some issue with the newer anniversary update. But still some other operations which involve dictation and listview loading seem to lag a little.